# React <script> widget does't show up on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a function to add a script tag to the body of the document

```
const UseScriptComponent = ({url}, e) => {
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, [url]);

  return null
}
```

That I use inside my class as a component:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="dashboard">
                <UseScriptComponent url='https://link_to_widget.com' /> // Test link avaiable at next example
            </div>
        );  
    }
}
```

The link from the script tag is supposed to show a floating button at the righ bottom corner of the screen
Nothing shows up at the screen, but the script is in fact added to the page as I can see on my Chrome DevTools elements tab.
I'm also supposed to init the widget using the code below, but I always get an error saying that `bbWidget` is not declared

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    bbWidget.init({
      widgetId: 'widget_uuid',
      merchantIds: [
        // list of merchant uuids (up to 5)
      ],
    });
});
```

At the network tab from Chrome DevTools I got this line:

```
Name: widget.js
Status: 200  
Type: script  
Initiator: dashboard.js  
Size: (disk cache)  
Time: 4ms
```

I tested this behaviour with another widget, created from taggbox, they gave me two options to embed it on my page:
Litecode:

```
<div class="taggbox" style="width:380px;height:500px;" data-widget-id="102233" data-tags="false"></div><script src="https://widget.taggbox.com/embed-lite.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and Iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://widget-lite.taggbox.com/102233?tags=false" style="width:380px;height:500px;border:none;"></iframe>
```

Only the second option worked, so I believe the problem is with the script tag
I've looked around for an answer but all I found was related to creating the UseScriptComponent or using Helmet as an alternative, so I'm really not sure where to go from here

Comment: And you're not using [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) because? Also removing a script tag doesn't actually unload the code so it's not clear why you'd bother, or why it needs to be a React component (*especially* since it will get added for every re-render), or why you're doing it at all....

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm sorry but I don't see how import() can help me here as the widget is on an external url. I edited the question to make it clear

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm sorry but there is not a single line in that page telling me that a url can be used, and I haven't heard of dynamic import before

Comment: Where is this `bbwidget...` code placed? Why don't you add the widget directly to the html?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it is a widget part of an API, its only avaiable through that source. I need to load the widget and then use the init code

Comment: So why do you first use the init code and then load the widget? How is this init code added to the html?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski At first I tried to copy/paste their recommended code, but then I got the error `bbWidget is not defined`. I will update the question with the API recommended code

Comment: Scripts cannot be injected into `document.body`, they can only be injected into `document.head`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is there any publication about that? I didn't know this

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I tried using Helmet to do such thing but still got the same result

Comment: helmet is an express library. It has zero effect on things that are already allowed to run in the browser, like your React app.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so how can I add this script tag to the Head of my react app?

Comment: You kinda of just... don't? If you need scripts loaded, you put that in your HTML template and make your React app load after those are done, _or_ you make those scripts part of your bundle. Your react app runs on a web page, and web pages have a perfectly well established way to load scripts. Instead of trying to do things in React, remember that React itself runs _on a webpage_ that you can do normal traditional web page things to, outside of React.

Comment: "There is not a single line in that page telling me that a url can be used" what about `await import("/modules/my-module.js");`? Do you not understand that the browser (which may be on the other side of the planet) has no knowledge of the file system on your *server* and converts those imports into urls to make HTTP requests for JS files even for static imports? "I haven't heard of dynamic import before" yes which is why I tried to help you by posting the link to the docs on it.